# How can i add more header details in header part of the JSON?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, web, frontend, software-design

```
"getOperationAddResponseFormData": [
        {
            "type": "",
            "description": "",
            "format": "",
            "headers": [
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "",
                    "description": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
```

I am working on a feature where user can add as many responses as they want but at the same time each response can have as many headers as the user wants . above is the JSON that gets generated when the user submits it .
Now what I am trying to achieve is that lets say the user adds a response say (500) then they add 2 headers(each having name,type,desc) . then upon submitting the below JSON should be generated

```
"getOperationAddResponseFormData": [
        {
            "type": "",
            "description": "",
            "format": "",
            "headers": [
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "",
                    "description": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "",
                    "description": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "type": "",
                    "description": ""
                }

            ]
        }
    ],
```

Code Sandbox Link( **refer ParamsFormTestTwo.js and App.js**). Just Hit Submit and you would be able to see the JSON in console :
https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-ganguly-gqlb4g?file=/src/App.js

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski so the problem is when I add more headers and hit submit , only the first header details show up and the others don't . So I want like a list of header details inside the header key of the JSON